# PHP and pgAdmin give different results in a query

Tags: php, postgresql, pgadmin

I have a SQL query in PHP

```
$sqlAcontecimento = "SELECT * FROM rm.acontecimento_x_entidade AS ae 
            INNER JOIN rm.acontecimentos AS ac ON ae.acontecimento_id = ac.entidade_id
            INNER JOIN entidade.entidades AS aee ON aee.entidade_id = ae.entidade_id
            INNER JOIN entidade.entidades AS ace ON ace.entidade_id = ac.entidade_id
            WHERE registro_id = (
                    SELECT entidade_id FROM contrato.contratos 
                    WHERE entidade_id NOT IN (SELECT contrato_origem_id FROM contrato.contratos WHERE contrato_origem_id IS NOT NULL)
                    AND codigo = '$clienteFirebird->N_PROPOSTA'
            ) AND aee.excluido = false AND ace.excluido = false
            AND descricao = '" . $anotacaoPainel->descricao . "'
            AND to_char(ocorrencia, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') = '$anotacaoPainel->cadastro'";
```

and if I echo it after I get:

```
SELECT * FROM rm.acontecimento_x_entidade AS ae INNER JOIN rm.acontecimentos AS ac ON ae.acontecimento_id = ac.entidade_id INNER JOIN entidade.entidades AS aee ON aee.entidade_id = ae.entidade_id INNER JOIN entidade.entidades AS ace ON ace.entidade_id = ac.entidade_id WHERE registro_id = ( SELECT entidade_id FROM contrato.contratos WHERE entidade_id NOT IN (SELECT contrato_origem_id FROM contrato.contratos WHERE contrato_origem_id IS NOT NULL) AND codigo = '294' ) AND aee.excluido = false AND ace.excluido = false AND descricao = 'Em contato titular ficou de fazer o pagto somente na primeira semana de dezembro.' AND to_char(ocorrencia, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') = '2015-11-25 11:07'
```

and it returns nothing. But if I run that same query in pgAdmin or console I get the expected results.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are all of your variables set properly?

Comment: Is your script connected to the same database?

Comment: Same database, same user.

Comment: Jay, I guess so. The query generated by PHP is right

Comment: If i do:
    $sql = <generated query copied in browser>
    $result = pg_query($conexaoPostgres, $sql);

i get the right result.